# AngularJS Route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

I am new in AngularJS. I am trying to learn AngularJS from this site (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07). My code is as below

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Angular Project</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">        
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

controllers.js

```
 var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

 phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function (data) {
                $scope.phones = data;
            });
            $scope.orderProp = 'age';
        }]);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId;
  }]);
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phonecatControllers'
]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

My code is inside `angu` folder of `htdocs` of my computer . I am trying to browse below URL

```
http://localhost/angu/#/phones
```

But I am getting white blank page. Could anyone say where is the problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You controller.js should have `phonecatControllers` module name instead of `phonecatApp`, So currently what happening is you are flushing the `phonecatApp` module by declaring it in `controller.js` again.

Technically you should be using `phonecatControllers` name there & you console must have showing an error `$injector moduler` error as you haven't declared the `phonecatControllers` module which has already injected in `phonecatApp` module.

**Controller.js**

```
var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []); //<=-change here

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function (data) {
         $scope.phones = data;
    });
    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
}]);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId;
}]);
```

Comment: @abuabu Glad to help you..Thanks :)